# JQuery UI Sortable - Can the placeholder be dynamically changed (to a different class, for example), depending on the container it is over?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to change the placeholder class when the sortable item is over a particular continer. So far I have used this:

```
$(".list").sortable({
    items: ".item",
    over: function (event, ui) {

        // For brevity, the calculation of condition has been omitted as it is irrelevant to the question.

        if( condition === true ){
            $(this).sortable( "option", "placeholder", 'new-placeholder-class' );
        }
    },
    placeholder: ".placeholder-class"
}).disableSelection();
```

I get this error

> Error: this.options.placeholder.update is not a function

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Please share an [mcve] of the code you've so far. Atleast take some time to properly format and share the code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out how to do the placeholder swap in the end. Instead of:

```
$(this).sortable( "option", "placeholder", 'new-placeholder-class' );
```

I used:

```
$(ui.sortable).removeClass("placeholder-class").addClass("new-placeholder-class");
```

This will change the placeholder class when over a particluar sortable container if defined within the 'over:' event function of the sortable definition.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. This works in the condition: 
`ui.placeholder.css("background-color", "#A33B2F");`